# Получить первый линк в блоке

Tags: c#, парсер, anglesharp

Подскажите пожалуйста как брать текст только из первой пары `<a></a>`.

```
<td rowspan="1" class="div_naimen">
    <a href="http://www.tools.by/?q=kat//p971673">Набор головок и бит 94пр.1/4",1/2" PRO STARTUL NEW CASE (PRO-094)+АКЦИЯ молоток антивибр. SE2001-01</a>
    <a href="http://www.tools.by/?q=node/34839&link_catalog" title="Товар участвует в акции. Покупай STRATUL, GEPARD, Le Notre и ВОЛАТ и получай подарки!">
        <img src="/si/icon_akcija.png" width="16" height="16">
    </a>
</td>
```

На данный момент пытаюсь сделать так :

```
var nameDoc = document.Result.QuerySelectorAll(@"td[class='div_naimen'] a");
```

но в результате получаю не только значение первой пары `<a></a>`, а всех пар `<a></a>` в этом блоке.

Comment: Юля, вам бы linq подучить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь linq, операторы .First или .FirstOrDefault (если не уверены, что такого элемента может и не быть на странице:

```
var elements = document.QuerySelectorAll("td.div_naimen a");

var firstUrl = elements.FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(firstUrl.GetAttribute("href"));

//  foreach (var element in elements)
//  {
//      var url = element.GetAttribute("href");
//      Console.WriteLine(url);
//  }
```

Ну или прям сразу в однострочник соединяйте:

```
Console.WriteLine(document.QuerySelectorAll("a").First().GetAttribute("href"));
```

PS Кстати, кто будет в linqpad этот пример пробовать запускать - обратите внимание, что вы должны будете добавить `<table>` к html, а не запускать оригинальный пример в котором сразу `<td>` идёт. Либо упростите выражение до `QuerySelectorAll("a")` чтобы найти элементы.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)