# C# вопрос по AngleSharp

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Нужная мне информация для парсинга храниться например в таком виде

```
<div class="rSide">
    <tr class="temperature">
       <td class="p1 ">+15°</td>
       <td class="p2 bR ">+14°</td>
       <td class="p3 ">+13°</td>
       <td class="p4 bR ">+16°</td>
       <td class="p5 ">+21°</td>
       <td class="p6 bR ">+23°</td>
       <td class="p7 cur">+21°</td>
       <td class="p8 ">+18°</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Каким образом парсить информацию о температуре , если div с класом rSide - единственный в документе, когда как тегов tr с класом temperature - много.

Comment: там разве нельзя xpath написать? или найти этот уникальный rside и проверять его потомки?

Comment: @tym32167 вот именно, не знаю как проверить его потомков.

Comment: ну вы узел найти можете? У узла есть свойство `Children` или что то наподобие того?

Comment: Приведенный фрагмент невалиден, поэтому вы не можете его распарсить. `tr` может быть только внутри `table`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Хорошо, а как мне например обратиться к потомку например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();

var document = parser.Parse(@"
<div class='rSide'>
    <table>
        <tr class='temperature'>
           <td class='p1 '>+15°</td>
           <td class='p2 bR '>+14°</td>
           <td class='p3 '>+13°</td>
           <td class='p4 bR '>+16°</td>
           <td class='p5 '>+21°</td>
           <td class='p6 bR '>+23°</td>
           <td class='p7 cur'>+21°</td>
           <td class='p8 '>+18°</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='temperature'>
           <td class='p1 '>+16°</td>
           <td class='p2 bR '>+15°</td>
           <td class='p3 '>+14°</td>
           <td class='p4 bR '>+17°</td>
           <td class='p5 '>+22°</td>
           <td class='p6 bR '>+24°</td>
           <td class='p7 cur'>+22°</td>
           <td class='p8 '>+19°</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
");

var temperaturesElements = document.QuerySelectorAll("div.rSide table tr.temperature");

foreach (var element in temperaturesElements)
{
    var p1 = element.QuerySelector("td.p1").Text();
    var p2 = element.QuerySelector("td.p2").Text();
    var p3 = element.QuerySelector("td.p3").Text();
    var p4 = element.QuerySelector("td.p4").Text();
//  $"p1={p1}".Dump();
//  $"p2={p2}".Dump();
//  $"p3={p3}".Dump();
//  $"p4={p4}".Dump();
//  "".Dump();
}
```

Вывод linqpad:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Два замечания.

1. Вероятно вам неплохо бы объявить класс в котором бы держать p1...pN - но это уже сами.
2. @Андрей NOP уже сказал, что приведённый html-код невалиден, добавлю. Я уже как-то [указывал при ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829934/213987) кому-то по тегу anglesharp что невалидный код не распознается. Вы будете долго и упорно дебажить - но ни за что не догадаетесь в чём ошибка. Я как-то раз пару часов убил на совершенно тривиальный пример.

И ещё. Не ленитесь, почитайте по тегу вопросы ранее заданные на ru so - ведь по anglesharp абсолютно однотипные вопросы, нужно лишь понимать селекторы дом.

Comment: Давно заданный вопрос,но все ещё актуальный.) Спасибо за ответ.)