# Подскажите,как правильно составить выражение для SelectNodes для HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Упражняюсь в парсинге, хочу получить данные со страницы.

Страница содержит резюме.

Как расположены блоки резюме на странице и как их отдать парсеру я разобрался, вопрос вот в чем, как мне в полученной части, (блок резюме), вытащить нужную информацию.

Из каждого блока я могу вытащить просто сам html и потом его разбирать дальше, но думаю, что так не рационально.

Вот что у меня в коде.

Как выбрать из этого блока например заголовок резюме, у заголовка такой тег `<h2 data-ga="resumeListItem">Главный бухгалтер</h2>` и его описание, оно  между div>p , а в этом месте содержится  нужная информация, внутри еще вложенный элемент `<dl class="prof-path-">`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace probaparser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string uri = "https://www.rabota66.ru/resume/rbranch1";

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument Doc1 = new HtmlDocument();

            Doc1.LoadHtml(Get(uri));

            ////*[@id='resume-list']/ul  // лист с резюме

            var g = Doc1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='vrl-one vrl-one-2 vrl-detaled- show- clearfix']/div[3]"); // собрал со страницы все блоки с резюме

            foreach (var n in g)
            {
                var zagolovok = n.InnerHtml; // вот весь html собираю, но это не верно.

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string Get(string url)
        {

            try
            {
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                httpWebRequest.Referer = "http://google.com"; /
                using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(httpWebResponse.CharacterSet)))
                        {
                            return reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот html блока резюме

```
<li class="vrl-one vrl-one-2 vrl-detaled- show- clearfix" id="l-124548423">
    <div class="additional-right-panel" data-id="124548423" style="display: none;"><span class="pseudo-checkbox icon-unchecked"></span></div>

    <div class="vrlo-add">
        <div class="vrloa-img-grnd">
                    <a class="vrloa-img img_zoom" id="image-zoom-23174208" href="https://cdn3.zp.ru/resize/500/0/job/attaches/2016/10/5a/a4/5aa41460f76e8447e03c9790207b6503.jpg">
        <img alt="" src="https://cdn3.zp.ru/resize/170/0/job/attaches/2016/10/5a/a4/5aa41460f76e8447e03c9790207b6503.jpg">
        </a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
                $("#image-zoom-23174208").off('click').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                    var imagePlaceholder = $('#zoomedImagePlaceholder');
                    if(imagePlaceholder.length && !imagePlaceholder.is(':hidden')){
                        imagePlaceholder.hide();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if(imagePlaceholder.length == 0){
                    var body = $('body');
                        body.append('<div id="image-shadow" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:black; opacity:.25; z-index:9998;">&nbsp;</div><div id="zoomedImagePlaceholder" style="z-index:9999;position:fixed;padding:5px;background-color:white;box-shadow:2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)"><img src="/images/site/misc/resume-default.gif"><span class="icon-cancel-circle" style="font-size:20px;color:#fff;position:absolute;top: -10px;right: -10px;text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;cursor:pointer;"></span></div>');
                        imagePlaceholder = body.find('#zoomedImagePlaceholder');
                    }
                    var image = imagePlaceholder.find('>img');
                    var imageShadow = $('#image-shadow');
                    imageShadow.css('height', $(window).height());
                    if(image.length){
                    image.attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
                    image.load(function(){
                    var imageHeight = $(this).height();
                    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
                    $(this).parent().css('max-height',  windowHeight - 50);
                    $(this).css('max-height',  windowHeight - 60);
                    if(imageHeight >= windowHeight){
                        $(this).parent().css('top', 15);
                    }else{
                        $(this).parent().css('top', (windowHeight - imageHeight) / 2);
                    }

                    $(this).parent().css('left', ($(window).width() - 500) / 2);
                    });
                    imagePlaceholder.fadeIn(200);
                    imageShadow.fadeIn(200);
                    imagePlaceholder.off('click').on('click', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).fadeOut(200);
                        $('#image-shadow').fadeOut(200);
                    });
                    imageShadow.off('click').on('click', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).fadeOut(200);
                        $('#zoomedImagePlaceholder').fadeOut(200);
                    });
                    } else {
                    imageShadow.hide();
                    imagePlaceholder.hide();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>        </div>
        <b class="salary-">
            от 55 000 руб.            <div class="pb10"></div>        </b>
    </div>

    <div class="vrlo-base vrlo-base-alternative">
        <div class="pad-">
            <div class="top-line">


                <div class="a-links-" id="resumeInfo-124548423">


                    <!--

                                            <div class="lb-orange-box lb-margin"><a class="lb-orange-item" href="#"
                                                               onclick="return showInfo('');"
                                                               id="elID-resumeBuyContacts"></a>&nbsp;&ndash;                          </div>
                                            <div class="lb-orange-item lb-mark-it-opened" style="line-height: 20px">
                    <span class="ex-item lb-mark-btn"><span class="lb-dropdown"><span
                                    class="icon-Ic_arrow_drop_down_48px"></span></span></span>
                            <div class="lb-panel" style="display: none; right: 0;">
                                <div class="ex-item"><span class="lb-text-title ur-exclude"
                                                           onclick="hideResume(); return false;"
                                                           style="white-space: nowrap"><span
                                                class="bg-eye-blue"></span></span></div>
                                <div class="ex-item"><span class="lb-text-title ur-exclude"
                                                           onclick="hideUserResumes(, ); return false;"
                                                           style="white-space: nowrap"><span
                                                class="bg-eye-blue"></span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    -->

                </div>

            </div>

            <div style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 22px; padding: 0 0 6px 0;">
                                    <div class="date- darkgray-" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <span>обновлено:
                            Сегодня</span>
                        <!--<span
                            class="viewed-" id="cvd_">                            :                             </span>-->                    </div>

            </div>

            <div class="title-">
                <a href="/resume/124548423" class="title-" id="s-124548423">
                    <h2 data-ga="resumeListItem">Главный бухгалтер</h2>
                </a>
                <div class="lb-container" id="lb-container-124548423" style="top: -4px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div>

                <!--
                                            <div class="comments-count">
                                                    </div>
                                    -->                <p>
                    Жанна Альбертовна, 54 года (25.02.1964)                </p>

                <p>
                    полная занятость, полный рабочий день, готовa к командировкам                </p>
            </div>

            <!--
                <blockquote class="excerpts">
                                    </blockquote>
            -->
            <!--            <div class="vrl-contacts crr">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <span class="gray- hiddenPhone" rel=""
                              id="resumePhone-"></span>
                                                        <span class="gray- hiddenPhone" rel=""
                          id="resumePhone-"></span>
                            </div>-->



                            <dl class="prof-path-">
                    <p class="mt7 darkgray-">
                        8 мест работы, начиная с 1983 года                    </p>
                                        <p>
                        <b>Главный бухгалтер</b>, июль 2013&nbsp;– июль 2017                    </p>

                    <p>
                        АО "Новамаш" (Екатеринбург)                    </p>
                                            <p class="darkgray-">
                            ранее                            : Зам.фин.директора по бухгалтерскому и налоговому учету, Помощник депутата, Заместитель директора по экономике, Конструктор  РЭА                        </p>
                                    </dl>
            <!--
            <div class="mb15 pt15">
                            </div>
-->
            <div class="t-border-"></div>
                            <div class="vrloa-cats pt7 gray-">
                                            <span class="node-item-"><span class="r-node-"><a href="/resume/rbranch1">Бухгалтерия, финансы, банки</a></span>
                                                            &nbsp;<span class="r-items-">(Бухгалтерия, Отчетность, налогообложение, Первичная бухгалтерия, Управленческий персонал, Управленческий учёт, Учёт заработной платы, Учёт основных средств, Учёт счетов и платежей, Учёт ТМЦ (МПЗ))</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr cll"></div>
</li>
```

Вот что хочу вытащить.

```
<h2 data-ga="resumeListItem">Главный бухгалтер</h2>

<p>  Жанна Альбертовна, 54 года (25.02.1964)  </p>

<p> полная занятость, полный рабочий день, готовa к командировкам 

<dl class="prof-path-"> // в этом блоке весь текст, но там вложенные теги есть.
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример html (минимальный для понимания вопроса), образец можете посмотреть в [моих ответах по метке anglesharp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A213987+%5Banglesharp%5D+is%3Aanswer). Ссылка на конкретный сайт не подходит -- сегодня там одна разметка, а завтра другая: учитесь делать [MVCE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Я не уверен, может ли ваша библиотека такое делать и если да, то так, но вообще-то если (бы я это делал в anglesharp) вы получили набор div'ов с резюме - вам ничего не мешает обойти в цикле каждый блок и снова искать внутри h2 с нужным data-атрибутом и dl.prof-path-. В качестве примера отсылаю к [парсингу температуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/864214/213987): на странице много блоков с температурой (как у вас резюме), обхожу в цикле и снова ищу нужные мне селекторы. Ваша библиотека должна что-то похожее уметь.

Comment: @AK да в своем коде я уже собрал все резюме все блоки, вопрос теперь как внутри этого блока искать нужные теги, или вариант остается каждый блок сохранять html и потому уже в этом блоке отдельно  снова запускать  парсер и искать, но это много шагов получается

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала давайте взглянем на необходимые нам данные:

[image: Data]

Мы видим, что это обычный список (ul), который содержит в себе пункты (li) со своими данными. Давайте для начала распарсим все это:

1. Для начала загрузим данные, делается это двумя строчками:

   ```
   HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
   document.LoadHtml(html);
   ```
2. Далее нам нужно найти сам `ul`, смотрим что  у него уникальное. В данном случае это класс `visitor-resume-list`, это позволяет нам с легкостью взять сразу этот объект:

   ```
   var list = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@class='visitor-resume-list']");
   ```
3. Следующим этапом будет получение всех `li` заданного элемента. Если нам нужны все элементы, то мы можем указать просто `//li`, если определенного класса или id, то указываем это. В данном случае нам нужно все, по этому делает следующее (для примера делаю отдельной строкой, лучше наверно будет добавить в Xpath первой строки нужные нам элементы):

   ```
   var items = list.SelectNodes(".//li"); //точка, указывает на поиск именно в `list`, а не по всему html!
   ```
4. На этом этапе у нас уже будут все `li` элементы. Осталось нам из них вытянуть все, что нудно:

   - Имя вытянуть легко, имеет свой "тег":

     ```
     var name = item.SelectSingleNode(".//h2[@data-ga='resumeListItem']").InnerText;
     ```
   - С описанием чуть сложнее, ведь он находиться в безымянном `div`, но можно заметить, что он строго находится после `<div class="title-">`, а значит мы это можем использовать ибо как раз для таких целей есть замечательный помощник - `following-sibling`:

     ```
     var data = item.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='title-']/following-sibling::div").SelectNodes(".//p");
     ```
   - Осталось нам заполучить другие данные, но это уже сами.

В итоге мы получаем что то на подобии этого:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

var items = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='visitor-resume-list']/li");

foreach (var item in items)
{
    var name = item.SelectSingleNode(".//h2[@data-ga='resumeListItem']").InnerText;
    var data = item.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='title-']/following-sibling::div").SelectNodes(".//p");

    Console.WriteLine(name);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", data.Select(x => $"  {x.InnerText.Trim()}")));
}
```

Что на выходе даст нам следующее:

```
Менеджер
  Вася Пупкин, 19 лет (07.09.1998), не состоит в браке
  полная занятость, полный рабочий день, готов к командировкам
Начальник планово-экономическим отделом
  Петя Егоров, 33 года (16.03.1985), есть дети
  полная занятость, полный рабочий день
....
```

Кстати, советую взглянуть на этот [сайт](https://devhints.io/xpath), в свое время он очень мне помог в понятие XPath.
В общем, удачи. Надеюсь помог!

---

> пытаюсь дальше по вашему шаблону получить данные из `<dl class="prof-path-">`, не получается вытащить, как правильно подскажите пожалуйста.

Давайте взглянем на этот `<dl class="prof-path-">`:

```
<dl class="prof-path-">
    <p class="mt7 darkgray-"> 5 мест работы, начиная с 1975 года </p>
    <p> <b>Финансовый Консультант</b>, январь 2015&nbsp;– настоящее время </p>
    <p> Многопрофильный Холдинг (Екатеринбург) </p>
    <p class="darkgray-"> ранее : Финансовый Директор - Начальник Контрольно Ревизионного Управления, Главный бухгалтер-Финансовый директор, Финансовый директор, Начальник финансовой службы дивизии. </p>
</dl>
```

Что видим?
Некий элемент `dl` с определенным классом `prof-path-`. "Внутренности" данного тега содержать текст в тегах `p`, на классы этих тегов по сути нам все равно, так что смело можем брать все, пробуем:

- Сначала ищем этот `prof-path-`, используем точку вначале для поиска именно в нужном элементе, а не во всем html: `".//dl[@class='prof-path-']"`.
- Далее нам надо получить все `p` внутри этого тега, чуть изменим условие: `".//dl[@class='prof-path-']/p"`.
- Условие составили, применяем:

  ```
  var info = item.SelectNodes(".//dl[@class='prof-path-']/p");
  ```
- Вывод (заметьте, тут строит проверка на `null` ибо у некоторых анкет этих данных попросту нету!):

  ```
  if (info != null)
      Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", info.Select(x => $"   >{x.InnerText.Trim()}")));
  ```

Результат:

```
Бухгалтер на первичную документацию
  Маша Пупкина, 36 лет (10.05.1982), в браке
  полная занятость, полный рабочий день
   >1 место работы, начиная с 2007 года
   >бухгалтер, ноябрь 2007&nbsp;&ndash; февраль 2012
   >ООО "красивое название" (Екатеринбург)
Начальник контрольно-ревизионного отдела
  Вася Пупкин, 61 год (04.05.1957), в браке
  частичная занятость, полный рабочий день, готов к командировкам
   >5 мест работы, начиная с 1975 года
   >Финансовый Консультант, январь 2015&nbsp;&ndash; настоящее время
   >Многопрофильный Холдинг (Екатеринбург)
   >ранее                            : Финансовый Директор - Начальник Контрольно Ревизионного Управления, Главный бухгалтер-Финансовый директор, Финансовый директор, Начальник финансовой службы дивизии.
```

Как видим, имеются лишние теги и пробелы, их естественно стоит подчистить! Но это уже совсем другая история)

Comment: Какие у вас всё-таки обстоятельные ответы, Евгений.

Comment: @AK Так убирается много лишних вопросов =)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо большое за помощь, достал информацию о зарплате, а вопрос ,пытаюсь дальше по вашему шаблону получить данные из <dl class="prof-path-">, не получается вытащить, как правильно подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Дополнил.

Comment: Спасибо большое